# Running a query on records being dumped by mysqldump

Tags: mysql

Is that possible? What I have is a table (let's say its name is userlist, in a base maindb), with two columns that contain sensitive information (let's call them pers1 and pers2), and now I need to periodically release a public version of that database. What I do now is:

First,

```
create database dummydb;
use dummydb;
create table `dummydb`.`userlist` like `maindb`.`userlist`;
insert into `dummydb`.`userlist` select * from `maindb`.`userlist`;
update `dummydb`.`userlist` set `pers1` = ' ', `pers2` = ' ';
```

Next, `/usr/bin/mysqldump -u %user% -p%password% dummydb > dummydb.sql`

Then, `drop database dummydb;`

After that I launch a tool that works with that dumped sql. What I need to know is whether I can do that update without creating a dummy db and juggling the table. Yes, I know I can also parse the dump, but maybe there is a less roundabout way I'm just not aware of?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to tell `mysqldump` to omit or overwrite columns, so I think your method may be as good as you can get.

Comment: Thanks! Omitting columns isn't a way anyway, 'cause the tool using the dump requires all columns to exist and have printable characters.

Comment: If you want to redact production data, which is a good idea generally speaking, it's usually a good idea to replace existing data with random data of the same length. Some applications won't work at all if things like a person's name are missing because there's nothing to click on.

Answer (score 2):

The file produced by mysqldump is just a flat file containing SQL statements. It also contains some statements that are not SQL, they're [builtin commands for the mysql client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html). So even if you had a tool that could parse the SQL of the dump file, it would also need to parse commands that are only understood by the mysql client.

The easiest path forward for your task is to use an instance of mysqld, import the dump file, and manipulate the sensitive data using SQL.

If you want a temporary instance of mysqld, so you can import your dump file without risking clobbering any real data, you might try launching a sandbox instance of mysqld using a tool like https://www.dbdeployer.com

Another option is to use the `mysqldump --tab` option when you create the dump. This writes data into CSV files, one per table, instead of SQL script files. There are many tools you can use to manipulate data in a CSV file. There are even command-line tools that allow you to use SQL against CSV files (see https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2015/08/20/csv-query-tools/)

Comment: Yes, I thought of that at first, but the dummy database approach seems to be simpler. And definitely simpler than using a specialized instancing tool, but thank you anyway ^_^

Comment: It depends on your dump file. Some people dump in a way that can be imported to a dummy database. Others dump with CREATE DATABASE statements within the dump file, so you'd have to edit those out if you want to import the dump to a dummy database. You could accidentally clobber your real database. That's why I like to launch a distinct mysqld instance, so I have a safeguard against that.